# DDS on ROS osrf prototype

Tags: ros, catkin-make, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody.
At the moment I'm trying do build a DDS implementation on ROS. The only code I found about it was the
https://github.com/osrf/ros_dds .
I've build the cpp example and it worked, but when I want to build the prototype, the catkin_make is not working

```
***DDS parse error DDS undefined at line: 27 (searching from scope 'Time_')
make[2]: *** [~/ros_dds/ros_dds-master/prototype/devel/include/std_msgs/dds_impl/Time_.h] Error 255
make[1]: *** [ros-packages/std_msgs/CMakeFiles/std_msgs_generate_messages_idlcpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  7%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  7%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_idl
[  7%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Is there any solution for this?
Is there any other prototype or developed thing?
I don't want to wait until ROS2 is released :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212099/dds-on-ros-osrf-prototype/) by [Rosewood](https://answers.ros.org/users/22353/rosewood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-25**:
Are you really trying to implement DDS on top of ROS? The repo you refer to as well as ROS 2 implement ROS on top of DDS.

**Comment by [Rosewood](https://answers.ros.org/users/22353/rosewood/) on 2015-06-26**:
Yeah, that was the plan. I want to have a showcase for DDS, favoring it with ROS (e.g. using gazebo) and I'm very interested in using ROS. I thought there'd be more development of it. Next I'll try the one of William down there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is also the work done by these guys to use DDS as a transport option in ROS 1: http://cyberdb.github.io/micROS-RT/

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look at the repositories in the [ros2](https://github.com/ros2/) organisation on GitHub. In particular the [ros2/examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples) package.

Know that none of this has been released though, it is all prototyping and initial development.

It is also far from a 'normal' ROS release (ie: no functionality other than the middleware and build infrastructure at the moment).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosewood](https://answers.ros.org/users/22353/rosewood/) on 2015-07-28**:
Thanks for the answers. The Version of William works very well. Those guys did a good job and they've already released a paper.